# Ruby string strip defined characters

Tags: ruby, string, strip

In Python, we can use the [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method of a string to remove leading or trailing occurrences of chosen characters:

```
>>> print " (Removes (only) leading & trailing brackets & ws ) ".strip(" ()")
'Removes (only) leading & trailing brackets & ws'
```

How do we do this in Ruby? Ruby's [`strip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-strip) method takes no arguments and strips only whitespace.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such method in ruby, but you can easily define it like:

```
def my_strip(string, chars)
  chars = Regexp.escape(chars)
  string.gsub(/\A[#{chars}]+|[#{chars}]+\z/, "")
end

my_strip " [la[]la] ", " []"
#=> "la[]la"
```

Comment: +1: I like this. It also looks like `#{chars}` automagically escapes regex metacharacters - is that right? If it were just string substitution, the regex shouldn't work in your example. However, you might want to use `\A` and `\Z` instead of `^` and `$` - the latter ones will also match around newlines which might not be desired.

Comment: @Tim: `#{}` doesn't escape - that's why I have the call to Regexp.escape in there. Good point about \A and \Z.

Comment: Oh. My fault - (wer lesen kann, ist klar im Vorteil).

Comment: thanks, just added: `return string unless string && chars` at beginning of function to handle nil for either inputs.

Answer (score 3):

```
"[[ ] foo [] boo ][ ]".gsub(/\A[ \[\]]+|[ \[\]]+\Z/,'') 
=> "foo [] boo"
```

Can also be shortenend to

```
"[[ ] foo [] boo ][ ]".gsub(/\A[][ ]+|[][ ]+\Z/,'') 
=> "foo [] boo"
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such method in ruby, but you can easily define it like:

```
class String
    alias strip_ws strip
    def strip chr=nil
        return self.strip_ws if chr.nil?
        self.gsub /^[#{Regexp.escape(chr)}]*|[#{Regexp.escape(chr)}]*$/, ''
    end
end
```

Which will satisfy the requested requirements:

```
> "[ [] foo [] boo [][]] ".strip(" []")
 => "foo [] boo"
```

While still doing what you'd expect in less extreme circumstances.

```
>  ' _bar_ '.strip.strip('_')
 => "bar"
```

nJoy!

Answer (score 1):

Try the [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000822) method:

```
irb(main):001:0> "[foo ]".gsub(/\As+[/,'')
=> "foo ]"

irb(main):001:0> "foo ]".gsub(/s+]\Z/,'')
=> "foo"
```

etc.

Comment: This, like all the other answers, removes all occurrences of the given characters. The OP only wants to remove the occurrences at either end of the string (like strip, but not only for whitespace).

Comment: Whoops, thought ^ matched the start of the string. Changed.

Comment: @Peter: I didn't actually see the ^ (which might be because it was in front of the opening `/` instead of behind it). But `\A` is more correct, yes. +1

Comment: Try this on `[ [] foo [] boo [][]] `. Your regexes will return the string unchanged because they rely on a particular order of the characters. Also, there's a `\\` missing.

Comment: @Tim From my understanding of the OP requirements returning ``[] foo [] boo [][]`` for your example would be correct behaviour.

Comment: No, in Python `"[ [] foo [] boo [][]] ".strip(" []")` returns `"foo [] boo"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
str.chomp('.')
that works for trailing characters and you can reverse the string for leading characters:
str.reverse.chomp('.').reverse

To do both at once you can:
str.chomp('.').reverse.chomp('.').reverse

Note: chomp removes only one occurrence by default

Answer (score 0):

Ruby now includes full support for stripping with

lstrip:    Strips only leading part of string
rstrip:    Strips only ending part of string
strip:     Strips both leading and ending of string

Answer (score -1):

Try the `String#delete` method: (avaiable in 1.9.3, not sure about other versions)

Ex:

```
    1.9.3-p484 :003 > "hehhhy".delete("h")
     => "ey"
```

Comment: This isn't what the question asked for.