# Counting and removing leading characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I have strings that contain a variable number of leading hyphens and which may or may not contain a hyphen in the body of the string. For example:

--xxx-xxx

-xxxx

---xxxxxx-xx

How do I in Ruby a) count the number of leading hyphens and b) return the string with the leading hyphens removed?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> "--xxx-xxx"[/\A-+/].size
=> 2
>> "--xxx-xxx".sub(/\A-+/, '')
=> "xxx-xxx"
```

EDIT: The comment from @shime made me want to show the other relevant capability of `String#[]` or `String#slice`:

```
>> "--xxx-xxx"[/\A-+(.+)/, 1]
=> "xxx-xxx"
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Very helpful.  Only thing is that I found that if there were no leading hyphens [/\A-+/] returns nil so [/\A-+/].size gives an error.  I got around this by calling .to_s.  Let me know if there is a more elegant way.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove leading hyphens:

```
.sub(/^-*/, "")
```

Count leading hyphens by subtracting the length of the string before and after the removal.

Answer (score 0):

For removing leading hyphens:

```
str.sub(/^-+(.+)/, '\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '---xx-x'
new_s = s.gsub(/\A-*/, '')
hyph_num = s.length - new_s.length
```

gsub removes leading hyphens. And the difference between s and new_s length equals the number of leading hyphens.

Comment: No need for gsub here, you're using a repeating regex with an anchor so sub will work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0

"-----xxx---xxx---".each_char do |ch|
  break if ch != '-'
  count = count + 1
end

# => 5


"-----xxx---xxx---".sub(/^-+/, '')
# => "xxx---xxx---"
```

Comment: You should anchor your expression, if there's no leading hyphens then the next set will be removed and that's probably not what the OP wants: "xxx---xxx---".sub(/-+/, '') #=> "xxxxxx---"

Comment: i thought this was in c for the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Read [Ruby string strip defined characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165891/ruby-string-strip-defined-characters) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3166005/284795

Then compare the length of the naked string and the original string

Comment: I was thinking of Python's strip, which can strip specific characters.